# convert weird character in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have the following character:

```
E=MCÂ²
```

I have the following code:

```
$xml.="      <author initial=\"EM\"><![CDATA[E=MCÂ²]]></author>\n";
```

For some reason, when I try to use this inside XML it throws this:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 897 at column 36: Encoding error
```

I'm using `perl` to handle the XML translation.

What do I need to do in the `perl` code that fixes this?

**I have no clue how to code this since im still fairly new to perl else i'd post what ive done**

Comment: You probably need the `use utf8` pragma because your source code contains utf8 encoded data, and you might need to set the handle that you are writing `$xml` to to `binmode`. I'm assuming this is in a CGI program, so you'd have to do `binmode STDOUT` at the very least. Furthermore, make sure your XML has the correct charset information. Without a little more information about your program it's hard to say though. You could create a [mcve] that reproduces this.

Comment: Isnt there a library for encoding? I shouldn't have to do all this. I should be able to pass this character through some sort of encoding manipulation and not have to modify the architecture of my code.

Comment: You don't need a library. You need to write your program correctly. If your source code contains utf8 characters, you need to tell Perl about that. Of course you could convert every character to html entities with some library, but then you do not need CDATA. The idea of that thing is that you can have literally whatever you want inside it. But you need to tell Perl what encoding your output has. That's completely unrelated to your _architecture_. Please create a [mcve]. With the current description it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: What @simbabque is telling you is that you need things like `use utf8;` (for characters literaly typed in your source) and `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` (or binmode) for I/O (and probably nothing else).  These are the "libraries" you ask about, but again as simbabque says it amounts to writing the program correctly. Please post your code.

Comment: Or, as [xxfelixxx shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518232/4653379), using the right tool for the task itself (XML here) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add the encoding information to the start of the XML string:

**xml_example.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>' . "\n";
$xml   .= "<author initial=\"EM\"><![CDATA[E=MCÂ²]]></author>\n";

my $dom;
eval {
    $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );
};

if ($@) {
    print "ERROR: " . $@;
} else {
    print $dom->toString();
}
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<author initial="EM"><![CDATA[E=MCÂ²]]></author>
```